# LinkedDataSailGraph - No parser factory available for RDF format JSON-LD

Tags: java, tinkerpop

We're trying to use the LinkedDataSailGraph along with Gremlin to do some funky stuff with traversals, inference. Unfortunately, just instantiating the class causes this error. Any ideas?

`new LinkedDataSailGraph(new MemoryStoreSailGraph());`

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No parser factory available for RDF format
>   JSON-LD (mimeTypes=application/ld+json; ext=jsonld)  at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.sail.impls.LinkedDataSailGraph.createSail(LinkedDataSailGraph.java:22)
>   at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.sail.impls.LinkedDataSailGraph.(LinkedDataSailGraph.java:14)
>   at
>   org.isatools.bii.benchmarking.QueryBenchmark.testLoading(QueryBenchmark.java:71)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)  at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)  at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: org.openrdf.rio.UnsupportedRDFormatException: No parser
>   factory available for RDF format JSON-LD
>   (mimeTypes=application/ld+json; ext=jsonld)  at
>   org.openrdf.rio.Rio.createParser(Rio.java:184)  at
>   net.fortytwo.linkeddata.rdfizers.VerbatimRdfizer.(VerbatimRdfizer.java:26)
>   at
>   net.fortytwo.linkeddata.LinkedDataCache.createDefault(LinkedDataCache.java:139)
>   at
>   net.fortytwo.linkeddata.sail.LinkedDataSail.(LinkedDataSail.java:50)
>   at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.sail.impls.LinkedDataSailGraph.createSail(LinkedDataSailGraph.java:20)
>   ... 25 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but it expect to have the JSON-LD Parser: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.jsonld-java%7Cjsonld-java%7C0.2%7Cjar

Answer (score 1):

Hi hi I had the same problem, I have resolved as suggested by @wikier.

here there are the working dependencies for maven:

```
<!-- json-ld -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jsonld-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonld-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jsonld-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonld-java-sesame</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

or if you need them for other systems (sbt, etc), you can check them here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jsonld-java